# cxx_destruct running rampant with EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes while running XCTests

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

In my decently large RestKit-based app, I have about 750 unit tests, with a significant number exercising code that uses `RestKit` with `CoreData`.  Recently, we've observed sporadic `EXC_BAD_ACCES0` crashes happening about 50% of the time for `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.  A decent number of the crashes identify "`cxx_destruct`" in the stack-trace related to either `RKObjectManager` or `RKObjectManagedStore`.

I noticed a comment in the `RestKit` code [here on github](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/71407f8c6e104b9701e76c6d3de9410dee5c54cb/Code/Network/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m#L455).

Currently, I'm trying to run my unit tests through Instruments with Zombie detection to try and track this down, but it's wonky in it's it setup to do this and I'm not confident it's actually detecting zombies.

I'm running `RestKit 0.22.0`.

Any ideas on what's wrong here?

Example crash log (I have many like this, but they are never precisely the same. `cxx_destruct` is common between them though):

```
Process:         XXXX [50359]
Path:            /Users/USER/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/*/XXXX.app/XXXX
Identifier:      XXXX
Version:         0
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd_sim [50332]
Responsible:     launchd_sim [50332]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-07-10 13:59:28.751 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.3 (13D65)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  8B81673C-B92D-28D3-9940-47C83C140C8E


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: NSManagedObjectContext Queue

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000008be84599

External Modification Warnings:
Debugger attached to process.

VM Regions Near 0x8be84599:
    __LINKEDIT             000000002010d000-0000000020113000 [   24K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000008fe17000-000000008fe24000 [   52K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld

Application Specific Information:
objc[50359]: Method cache corrupted. This may be a message to an invalid object, or a memory error somewhere else.
objc[50359]: receiver 0x2b48380, SEL 0x240d6cc, isa 0x9d9210a, cache 0x9d92112, buckets 0xc80000, mask 0x0, occupied 0x8
objc[50359]: receiver 0 bytes, buckets 0 bytes
objc[50359]: selector 'release'
iPhone Simulator 463.9.41, iPhone OS 7.1 (iPhone Retina (4-inch)/11D167)


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: NSManagedObjectContext Queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x02f29286 __kill + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x02f275ec kill$UNIX2003 + 32
2   libsystem_sim_c.dylib           0x02c2e35b raise + 26
3   XXXX                            0x00152bf8 CLSSignalHandler + 246 (CLSSignal.m:305)
4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x02dfddeb _sigtramp + 43
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x023f5817 cache_t::bad_cache(objc_object*, objc_selector*, objc_class*) + 215
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x023f573f objc_msgSend_corrupt_cache_error + 31
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0240710d objc_msgSend + 105
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0282bbf0 CFRelease + 272
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0285eb82 -[__NSArrayI dealloc] + 82
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x02408692 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 268
11  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x02409aeb -[NSObject release] + 25
12  CoreData                        0x008fd7c0 _NSQLRow_dealloc_standard + 128
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0284c906 __CFBasicHashRemoveValue + 118
14  CoreFoundation                  0x0284c7a4 CFBasicHashRemoveValue + 2580
15  CoreFoundation                  0x02859aa6 CFDictionaryRemoveValue + 198
16  CoreData                        0x00906ff7 -[NSPersistentStoreCache forgetExternalDataForObjectID:] + 39
17  CoreData                        0x00906f8a -[NSPersistentStoreCache decrementRefCountForObjectID:] + 90
18  CoreData                        0x00906ece -[NSSQLCore managedObjectContextDidUnregisterObjectsWithIDs:] + 206
19  CoreData                        0x009cf870 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) _informAffectedStoresOfInterestByChildContextInObjectsWithObjectIDs:withSelector:] + 928
20  CoreData                        0x00906def -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) managedObjectContextDidUnregisterObjectsWithIDs:] + 47
21  CoreData                        0x009a83d2 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _informParentStoreNoLongerInterestedInObjectIDs:] + 450
22  CoreData                        0x009accb2 __97-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) managedObjectContextDidUnregisterObjectsWithIDs:]_block_invoke + 66
23  CoreData                        0x0092eb81 internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 17
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x02bbe4d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x02bab740 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 58
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x02bab3ea dispatch_barrier_sync_f + 89
27  CoreData                        0x0092eb02 _perform + 114
28  CoreData                        0x009315a9 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) managedObjectContextDidUnregisterObjectsWithIDs:] + 73
29  CoreData                        0x0093bd7c -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _disposeObjects:count:notifyParent:] + 492
30  CoreData                        0x0093b392 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _dispose:] + 578
31  CoreData                        0x0093ae5f -[NSManagedObjectContext _dealloc__] + 319
32  CoreData                        0x0093acf6 -[NSManagedObjectContext dealloc] + 70
33  CoreData                        0x008fdced -[NSManagedObjectContext release] + 77
34  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x02407e97 objc_release + 71
35  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x02407e3e objc_storeStrong + 39
36  XXXX                            0x00202095 -[RKManagedObjectStore .cxx_destruct] + 69 (RKManagedObjectStore.m:125)
37  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x023f62d4 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 128
38  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x023f624f object_cxxDestruct + 20
39  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0240127a objc_destructInstance + 48
40  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x024012ab object_dispose + 20
41  XXXX                            0x001fc9a0 -[RKManagedObjectStore dealloc] + 144 (RKManagedObjectStore.m:178)
42  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x02408692 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 268
43  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x02407e81 objc_release + 49
44  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x02407e3e objc_storeStrong + 39
45  XXXX                            0x0022d1cf -[RKObjectManager .cxx_destruct] + 335 (RKObjectManager.m:346)
46  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x023f62d4 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 128
47  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x023f624f object_cxxDestruct + 20
48  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0240127a objc_destructInstance + 48
49  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x024012ab object_dispose + 20
50  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x02408692 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 268
51  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x02407e81 objc_release + 49
52  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x02408ce7 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 537
53  XCTest                          0x20103dbe -[XCTestCase performTest:] + 178
54  XCTest                          0x20104c48 -[XCTest run] + 82
55  XCTest                          0x201033e8 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 139
56  XCTest                          0x20104c48 -[XCTest run] + 82
57  XCTest                          0x201033e8 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 139
58  XCTest                          0x20104c48 -[XCTest run] + 82
59  XCTest                          0x201033e8 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 139
60  XCTest                          0x20104c48 -[XCTest run] + 82
61  XCTest                          0x201066ba +[XCTestProbe runTests:] + 183
62  Foundation                      0x0202d5ec __NSFireDelayedPerform + 372
63  CoreFoundation                  0x02868ac6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
64  CoreFoundation                  0x028684ad __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1181
65  CoreFoundation                  0x02850538 __CFRunLoopRun + 1816
66  CoreFoundation                  0x0284f9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
67  CoreFoundation                  0x0284f7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
68  GraphicsServices                0x0371a5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
69  GraphicsServices                0x0371a42b GSEventRun + 104
70  UIKit                           0x0103ff9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
71  XXXX                            0x000a4ed8 main + 216 (main.m:16)
72  libdyld.dylib                   0x02df3701 start + 1
```

Comment: What changed before the exceptions started?

Comment: Great question.  Nearly impossible to say, because this started happening months ago, and we never really considered an issue until recently.  Don't flame me, please

Comment: Do you know which tests fail and which pass (is it consistent)? I'd say you need to try to localise the issue to some particular cases that can be analysed. Possibly turning all tests off and them progressively turning on...